# I am using dell XPS laptop. Core i5 ; Brightness of screen never reduces

Tags: 10.04

Brightness of my screen never reduces when using function keys nor when i change the settings in power management.

i also rebooted the laptop after changing the setting but brightness dint reduce.

Please help!
Regards,
Shantanu.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,